# Chmod invalid command, Ubuntu server

Tags: server, permissions, chmod

I am trying to give the user tomcat8 write and read access to a specific folder on my server.
I tried this command:

```
sudo chmod -R tomcat8 /usr/local/javaagent/appagent/ver2/logs/Tomcat1
```

However it gives me

```
chmod: invalid mode: `tomcat8'
```

Why doesn't this work? Isn't this the standard `chmod`?

Comment: Won't that screw up the permissions for other users if I change the owner of that folder? @edwinksl

Comment: @MikeKorza chmod needs the permissions, like 777 or 755, and such.

Comment: It will not change permissions, it will change the owner. If you use chmon, you need to specify permissions you want to give, not a user. Read `man chmod`.

Comment: @MikeKorza Oops, I misread what you intended to do. As dadexix86 and Pilot6 said, `chmod` is correct but you need to specify permissions correctly. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions for some examples.

Comment: chmod doesn't provide the granularity to specify permissions for an individual user - only for the file's owner (`o`), group (`g`), or "other" (`o`). Probably the way to achieve what you want is to give the file's group rw permission, and make user tomcat8 a member of the group. Beyond that there are ACLs.

Comment: you want chown for that. not chmod.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this only with `chmod`. You can, however, make a new group and change the group ownership of the directory, add the user to that group and then give the *group* the permissions you want on the directory, so you can give privilege to only that group.

To create a group `tomcat` and add the user `tomcat8` to it:

```
sudo groupadd tomcat && sudo adduser tomcat8 tomcat
```

You may also want to add yourself (and any other users who need read write access here) to the group with `sudo adduser [username] tomcat`

Now change the group ownership of the directory:

```
sudo chown :tomcat /usr/local/javaagent/appagent/ver2/logs/Tomcat1
```

Don't forget the colon - this is to change only the group ownership.

Now change permissions, for example, you add read and write permissions to the group like this:

```
sudo chmod g+rw /usr/local/javaagent/appagent/ver2/logs/Tomcat1
```

From your question I'm not sure what you want the other settings to be. I recommend reading `man chmod` and [this guide to permissions](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php) to understand better what you are doing.

**Directories need execute permissions** to be entered and searchable, so you most likely want octal `775` (so all users can read and search but only group can write) or `770` (so only owner and group have any permissions - keeping the directory private)

Don't use `-R` as it's unlikely you want all files to have execute permission.

You probably do want to add the setgid bit though, so that files created here by all users inherit the same group ownership as the directory:

```
chmod g+s /usr/local/javaagent/appagent/ver2/logs/Tomcat1
```

Or using octal, in one step:

```
chmod 2775 /usr/local/javaagent/appagent/ver2/logs/Tomcat1
```

which gives these permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x
```

(the `s` in that position is the setgid bit) or

```
chmod 2770 /usr/local/javaagent/appagent/ver2/logs/Tomcat1
```

which gives

```
drwxrws---
```

To check permissions and owners on the directory, use `ls -ld`:

```
ls -ld /usr/local/javaagent/appagent/ver2/logs/Tomcat1
```