# Permission denied in 777 folder

Tags: permissions, chmod

```
john@ubuntu01:~$ sudo ls -l /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git
total 25068
drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git      4096 aug 14 19:58 branches
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git        66 aug 14 19:58 config
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root     4096 aug 15 14:56 custom_hooks
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git        73 aug 14 19:58 description
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git        23 aug 14 19:58 HEAD
lrwxrwxrwx  1 git  git        47 aug 14 19:58 hooks -> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks
drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git      4096 aug 14 19:58 hooks.old.1471193907
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git      1329 aug 15 14:48 index
drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git      4096 aug 15 13:58 info
drwxr-xr-x 71 git  git      4096 aug 15 14:55 objects
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git        98 aug 15 13:58 packed-refs
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git  25618530 aug 15 14:03 post-receive.log
drwxr-xr-x  5 git  git      4096 aug 14 20:31 refs
john@ubuntu01:~$ ls -l /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git
ls: cannot access '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git': Permission denied
```

Here are ACLs

```
john@ubuntu01:~$ sudo lsattr /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git/custom_hooks
-------------e-- /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git/custom_hooks/post-receive
```

I have never seen this before. No permission to LS even with 777?
I need to share this folder for more convenient development. How can I solve it? Thank you.

EDITED:
(here are your requests)

```
john@ubuntu01:~$ sudo ls -ld /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git
drwxrwxrwx 8 git git 4096 aug 15 14:48 /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git
john@ubuntu01:~$ sudo ls -ld /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git/custom_hooks
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 aug 15 14:56 /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git/custom_hooks
```

EDITED MORE

```
sudo ls -ld /var/opt/gitlab/git-‌​data/repositories/GL/‌​www.git
ls: cannot access '/var/opt/gitlab/git-‌​data/repositories/GL/‌​www.git': No such file or directory
```

hmmm... what is this?

Comment: the permissions of the directory you are `ls` ing are not shown?

Comment: is custom_hooks and have drwxrwxrwx  2 root root, see above

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git': Permission denied` so show us what happens when you `ls -ld /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git`

Comment: ls: cannot access '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GL/www.git/custom_hooks': Permission denied and this have 777 rights!

Comment: could you please do what I asked? if you don't have execute permission on the parent directory then 777 on this one will not help you

Comment: edited, ls -ld "No such file or directory" ??

Comment: Apparently your problem is higher up the tree then. Keep going up a level and examining the permissions, and you will find that one of them has no x permission for o, for example `drwxr-x---`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43995/discussion-between-zanna-and-user1797147).

Comment: @Zanna, many thanks, indeed, a upper directory was still under git:git ownership. SOLVED.

Comment: I wrote an answer for you & for reference for others

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This happens because there is a directory higher in the tree where you do not have execute permission. If a parent directory has no execute permission for some user, then that user cannot stat any subdirectories regardless of the permissions on those subdirectories.

**Example:**

```
$ ls -l cake
drwxr-xr-x 2 zanna zanna 4096 Jul 12 11:43 brownies
$ chmod 666 cake
$ ls -l cake/brownies
ls: cannot access 'cake/brownies': Permission Denied
```

Even though I am the owner of the directory 'brownies' and all users have permission to read and enter it, I can't access it if its parent directory has no execute permission.

It's better to [use groups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805203/chmod-invalid-command-ubuntu-server/805216#805216) to manage permissions than give to give directories 777 permission. Are you sure you need to do that?

**How to fix the problem in a more secure way:**

Let's assume on `/var/opt/gitlab` directory you have something like this:

```
drwxr-x--- 5 git git 4096 aug 14 17:30 gitlab
```

Add yourself and all the other users who need permission to the git group, for example:

```
sudo usermod -a -G john git
```

Users have to log out and back in for this to take effect. Even if write permission is needed on a subdirectory, you don't need to add it on a parent directory, by the way, so you don't have to use `chmod` at all. You might want to change your subdirectory permissions to prevent anyone from being able to write to it:

```
chmod 775 /var/opt/gitlab/git‌​-data/repositories/GL‌​/www.git/custom_hooks
```

or

```
chmod o-w /var/opt/gitlab/git‌​-data/repositories/GL‌​/www.git/custom_hooks
```

Comment: Thanks again, no, I was just testing some script. Feel much more comfortable to edit  with N++ on windows than rudimentary Gedit. Also rudimentary Nautilus which isn't able to CUT something then PASTE with making a new folder in the same time... or right click -> New Folder.